# Word Automation Find and Replace not including Text Boxes

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I have a word document which has a text box.  When i run an automated find and replace its matching in the main document, but not match anything in the Text Box.  How do i tell the find and replace function to include Text Boxes.

```
Word.Range range = objDoc.Content;

object findtext = Field;
object findreplacement = Value;
object findwrap = WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;
object findreplace = WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;

range.Find.Execute(findtext, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, findwrap, missing, findreplacement, findreplace);
```

I suspect i need to change the range = objDoc.content line.

Comment: Check this place out http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/36cebc60-7c7e-494c-ad2d-0dcebce5a706/

Some answers given on the process of searching text boxes, checks to see that it isnt part of the 'main story'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Slightly messy but this worked for me:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            const string documentLocation = @"C:\temp\Foo.docx";
            const string findText = "Foobar";
            const string replaceText = "Woo";

            FindReplace(documentLocation, findText, replaceText);
        }

        private static void FindReplace(string documentLocation, string findText, string replaceText)
        {
            var app = new Application();
            var doc = app.Documents.Open(documentLocation);

            var range = doc.Range();

            range.Find.Execute(FindText: findText, Replace: WdReplace.wdReplaceAll, ReplaceWith: replaceText);

            var shapes = doc.Shapes;

            foreach (Shape shape in shapes)
            {
                var initialText = shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
                var resultingText = initialText.Replace(findText, replaceText);
                shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = resultingText;
            }

            doc.Save();
            doc.Close();

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
        }
    }
}
```

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

Comment: Great - spent ages trying to work out where text boxes lived. `doc.Shapes` is a winner.

Comment: You can still use Find on a TextFrame's range, by the way. It just has to be a separate call. Only slightly annoying.

Comment: Very helpful for our project as well! One small comment: the shape may not have text (we have some shapes that do have it, and some that didn't, so shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text may throw an exception which has to be handled...

Comment: @AmittaiShapira Good point, I'm guessing with C#6 you can just use *shape?.TextFrame?.TextRange?.Text* now