# C# word replace all

Tags: c#, ms-word

```
 var WordApp = new Word.Application();
 var WordDocument = WordApp.Documents.Open(@"C:\\contract.docx");
 WordReplace("{seller_name}",
      dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString(), WordDocument);
```

I'm using this code for replace in word document. How can i replace not 1 time but several? I need to replace all {seller_name} in word.

Comment: Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256417/word-automation-find-and-replace-not-including-text-boxes

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://freeword.codeplex.com to do it.

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.LoadFromFile(@"C:\\contract.docx");
doc.Replace("{seller_name}", "Replace Value");
```