# Replace text in Word with text from C# form

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I'm trying to make an application in C#. When pressing a radio button, I'd like to open a Microsoft Word document (an invoice) and replace some text with text from my Form. The Word documents also contains some textboxes with text.

I've tried to implement the code written in this link [Word Automation Find and Replace not including Text Boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256417/word-automation-find-and-replace-not-including-text-boxes) but when I press the radio button, a window appears asking for "the encoding that makes the document readable" and then the Word document opens and it's full of black triangles and other things instead of my initial template for the invoice.

How my invoice looks after:
[image: & how it looks after]

Here is what I've tried:

```
    string documentLocation = @"C:\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Project\\Invoice.doc";
    private void yes_radioBtn_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FindReplace(documentLocation, "HotelName", "MyHotelName");
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = documentLocation;
        process.Start();
    }

    private void FindReplace(string documentLocation, string findText, string replaceText)
    {
        var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        var doc = app.Documents.Open(documentLocation);
        var range = doc.Range();

        range.Find.Execute(FindText: findText, Replace: WdReplace.wdReplaceAll, ReplaceWith: replaceText);

        var shapes = doc.Shapes;
        foreach (Shape shape in shapes)
        {
            var initialText = shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
            var resultingText = initialText.Replace(findText, replaceText);
            shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = resultingText;
        }

        doc.Save();
        doc.Close();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
    }
```

Comment: I had to stop reading on the first line. the purpose of the @ prefix is to avoid escaping, so there should be single backslashes, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @dlatikay double work just as good in some cases - although I've ran into it causing issues before.

Comment: the resulting file is corrupted, but there is no reason to blame your code, it looks fine so far. Could you use the .docx format instead? there is one functional issue that *could* become a problem. what if the replacement text by chance contains a text that is to be replaced in subsequent calls - that would mess up. consider using bookmarks instead of the replaceall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So if your word template is the same each time you essentially

- Copy The Template
- Work On The Template
- Save In Desired Format
- Delete Template Copy

Each of the sections that you are replacing within your word document you have to insert a bookmark for that location (easiest way to input text in an area).

I always create a function to accomplish this, and I end up passing in the path - as well as all of the text to replace my in-document bookmarks.  The function call can get long sometimes, but it works for me.

```
Application app = new Application();
Document doc = app.Documents.Open("sDocumentCopyPath.docx");


if (doc.Bookmarks.Exists("bookmark_1"))
        {
            object oBookMark = "bookmark_1";
            doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oBookMark).Range.Text = My Text To Replace bookmark_1;
        }
        if (doc.Bookmarks.Exists("bookmark_2"))
        {
            object oBookMark = "bookmark_2";
            doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oBookMark).Range.Text = My Text To Replace bookmark_2;
        }

                doc.ExportAsFixedFormat("myNewPdf.pdf", WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);

((_Document)doc).Close();
((_Application)app).Quit();
```

This code should get you up and running unless you want to pass in all the values into a function.

EDIT: If you need more examples I'm working on a blog post as well, so I have a lot more detail if this wasn't clear enough for your use case.

Comment: @Elena - Please mark my answer as correct if it suited your needs - I'm glad it helped! :)