# How do I replace text inside MS-Word textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word

I wrote a Windows Forms program using C#. It contains textboxes and a data-grid.

I want to export the data into a Word file to use the template. I added the library of Microsoft Word into my code.

Also I created textboxes "shapes" inside the Word file and putted inside them text to be find from my c# program

**For now everything seems okay, But I'm stuck at the C# side, I can replace the normal text, but not the text inside textboxes "Inside the word file"**

And here is my code:

```
private void FindAndReplace(Word.Application wordapp, object ToFindText, object replaceWithText)

        {
            object matchCase = true;
            object matchWholeWord = true;
            object matchWildCards = false;
            object matchSoundLike = false;
            object matchAllforms = false;
            object forward = true;
            object format = false;
            object matchKashida = false;
            object matchDiactitics = false;
            object matchAlefHamza = false;
            object matchControl = false;
            object matchread_only = false;
            object visible = true;
            object replace = 2;
            object wrap = 1;

            wordapp.Selection.Find.Execute(ref ToFindText,
                ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
                ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundLike,
                ref matchAllforms, ref forward,
                ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText,
                ref replace, ref matchKashida,
                ref matchDiactitics, ref matchAlefHamza,
                ref matchControl);

        }


        private void CreateWordDocument(object filename, object SaveAs)
        {
            Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
            object missing = Missing.Value;
            Word.Document myWordDoc = null;

            if (File.Exists((string)filename))

            {
                object readOnly = false;
                object isVisible = false;
                wordApp.Visible = false;

                myWordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref missing, ref readOnly,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

                myWordDoc.Activate();

                //find and replave
                this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<date1>", textBox2.Text);
                this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<date2>", textBox3.Text);

            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File not found!");
            }

            //Svae as
            myWordDoc.SaveAs2(ref SaveAs, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);


            myWordDoc.Close();
            wordApp.Quit();
            MessageBox.Show("File Created!");


         }
```

Comment: You don't provide enough information. What kinds of fields? Word has many, many kinds. Also, why not use *Bookmarks* as the data targets? Or content controls? In addition to this information you should show us the basic code you have to interact with Word. That's more relevant to the problem than the WinForms code you included... Use the [edit] link below the Question to add supplemental information directly to the question, please

Comment: Any kind of field or bookmark, I just want to make it work, I didn't include the c# code that can fill the data into the word file because seriously I didn't understand how that's work, I deleted everything and want to start from scratch to understand, I tired a lot of examples, nothing work for me, I'm working on this from a week..

Comment: @CindyMeister I just update my question

Comment: Are you working with .doc or with .docx files? if it is .docx you should stop using the interop library and switch to the [OpenXML SDK the Microsoft Office team provides on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/). It is much more modern and does not rely on COM so you don't need to worry about instances of word.exe being left open due to improper cleanup of resources.

Comment: In MS-Word as Text Box is a Shape. So you have to iterate through the Shapes and find those that are Text Boxes. Then it's a simple Shape.Range.Text command to pickup the content.

Comment: Word has more than one kind of "text box". Please explain which commands you used to put the "text box" into the document. Also, do you need "boxes"? Or only "target points" your code can write to?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thanks for the advice, but I don't know how to use it, it takes me a week to use the normal word library to make it work, but I will check it

Comment: @RichMichaels Can you please tell me what should I change in my code to make it read what inside the shape?

Comment: @CindyMeister My code look on text inside the word document and then replace it with another text, it doesn't insert text boxes, my problem is my code only can read normal text "paragraphs" not the text inside the shape "textbox"

Comment: Your question has been asked before. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256417/word-automation-find-and-replace-not-including-text-boxes